# Is my general approach to proofs acceptable? A general topology example.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, soft-question, education

Proving: $A$ is closed iff $A = \bar{A}$.

*"To the right"*: **If $A$ is closed, $ A = \bar A$**

If $A$ is closed this means that it contains all of its own accumulation points. And we would find that its derived set would be a subset of $A$. i.e. $ A' \subset A$  And we know that the closure of a set is equal to the union of its derived set and itself. So if $ A' \subset A$ then $ A' \cup A = A$ Therefore $\bar A = A$

*"To the left"*: **If $A = \bar A$ then $A$ is closed.**

If $A = \bar A$ we would be saying that the set A is equal to the intersection of all closed super-sets of A. One of the properties of closed sets is that the intersection of any number of closed sets is closed. Therefore $A$ is closed.

-

I wanted to show how I tend to prove things. Practicing proofs at random for a test I have tomorrow and hope to find out from you guys if my lengthy (wordy) approach to mathematical proofing is acceptable. This is a way that makes me feel confident in my understanding of the topics and is a lot more fulfilling for me than typing row after row of math symbols.

My other issue is citing previously taught theorems. How do I do that in such a way as to avoid using the numbering systems of different texts? One book may call that theorem, 2.1 and another 5.3. Most of our notes do not explicitly name theorems, so how do I use one theorem to prove another?

Seeing as I'm interested in doing a masters in mathematics next year I want to know if my way of looking at/explaining things or answering questions is acceptable at a higher level. I know at the moment my lecturers aren't always pleased by my "more paper please!" aproach to tests but I'd like to hear your opinions.

Comment: Just one question I want to know what is the relationship of all this with the linear algebra?

Comment: The proofs seem fine. There are shorter ones, e.g.: If $A$ is closed then $\bar A$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$ (hence $A\subseteq \bar A$) and one of these closed sets is $A$ (hence $\bar A\subseteq A$). But you do not have to come up with the shortest proof.

Comment: Oh! Oops! I meant topology, sorry and thanks. Studying topology now, but I'd just walked out of a linear algebra test this afternoon. Must be confused. Thank you!

Comment: I would criticize that the proof would appear more consistent if you used the same definitions of *being closed* or *closure* in both directions. For example, how do you know that if $A$ is closed, then it contains all accumulation points?

Comment: @StefanH. That's true. My other issue is citing previously taught theorems. How do I do that in such a way as to avoid using the numbering systems of different texts? One book may call that theorem, 2.1 and another 5.3. Most of our notes do not explicitly name theorems, so how do I use one theorem to prove another?

Comment: @Siyanda You just state the result of the theorem as you need to use it, just like how you would state the name of a theorem (if it had one) when you needed to use it.

Comment: How is a closed set defined in your situation? Is there a family of open sets defined for the setting, or are you given the neighborhood bases for the points in your set. It always largely depends on what is given/ how things are defined.